# E-commerce and Bootstrap

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system, e-commerce

I have been creating websites in html and Wordpress for a while, but recently I was asked to look at a website that had been created very badly with a bootstrap based CMS, they were ripped off big time.

I understand that Bootstrap is basically a collection of styles etc but what I do not seem to be able to find is how to integrate a bootstrap template that I will purchase into a website with e-commerce functionality. The template has all the needed shop pages etc I just need to know how I go about making the online shop using the template.

Comment: What CMS is it currently using? Do you have to stay on that CMS? Is this a one-off project or do you foresee yourself working on it repeatedly?

Comment: The company that did the site us Tagnia (london company)Its not good but I was not involved. We will move away from it and start again. I am going to get the basics up and running today on test hosting with new template. Later would need to add ecommerce features, the will only be limited products. Editing will be limited and I can do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is not a collection of styles -- its a templating system that modifies the layout of the web page content based on the users 'viewport'. in other words it changes the page design for smaller screens like mobile smart phones and tablets. its awesome for e-commerce especially considering the rising growth of sales over mobile,

but otherwise you don't make an online shop with a template, its kind of the other way around. so unless you really want to learn e-commerce programming, consider using a dedicated service like http://www.shopify.com If you want to integrate e-commerce with an existing website, http://www.foxycart.com is very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving it to a completely new setup and are comfortable using WordPress you could use that as a CMS and add e-commerce functionality using [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/). It's trivial to add the plugin and configure it, and customising it is straightforward as it has a pretty good template hierarchy system that makes it easy to override using your own custom templates. It also uses a comprehensive set of filters and actions so custom functionality can be added in future if required.

In terms of adapting an existing theme (Bootstrap-based or otherwise) to work with WooCommerce it's just a case of creating additional templates if required and adding some additional CSS if need be. I'd recommend doing that using a [child theme](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial) so that the parent theme can be updated in the future without overriding any of your customisations.

The advantage of this setup is that you're working on a platform you're comfortable with (WordPress) and there's a fair amount of support and articles available to help you along. The client would also benefit as it's a pretty popular solution, so they shouldn't have any trouble finding devs/or agencies to work on it in the future (just in case you aren't available).

One potential disadvantage is the WC can be a bit sluggish; I'd recommend not being cheap when it comes to your choice of hosts. I've used TSO before and would recommend them.